# How to use the column's scale correctly and elegantly

Tags: hibernate, bigdecimal

I am using `Hibernate` and I want to custom a column's scale, but it does not work as my expect.

Here is my code:

```
@Column(scale = 4)
private BigDecimal scaNum; //not work

@Column(scale = 4,precision = 19)
private BigDecimal scaPreNum; //work
```

Why it's not working if I just set scale value.

Comment: Can you specify one particular example where it didn't work

Comment: In the first situation:  it's scale =4 and column in database is "sca_num NUMBER(19,2)";
the secode situation : column in database is "sca_pre_num NUMBER(19,4)".

Comment: What is the error/exception you are facing?

Comment: I used "scale=4" in my code, but the column(sca_num) in database is (19, 2), it decimal places is 2, I want it is 4.

Comment: Can you share your hibernate configuration too?

Comment: Is there such a configuration? I did not find any thing about it.

Comment: I want to set scale only, and the precision I don't care precision(handled by hibernate).

Comment: The place where you specify your database connection properties

Comment: I don't think there exists something will make it work.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhIR2.png